# how to get a nested JSON with mulltiple foregin keys in a RESTful API with laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Hi i'm triying to make a RESTful API and i have this tables on my database, thing is i want to have a nested route like this

> localhost/foodGroup/{id}/portions/{id}/foods

and i want that to return a JSON with all the foods i have with the same portion and same foodGroup: this is my database:

```
foodGroup
    id - integer (primary key)
    name - string

portions
    id - integer (primary key)
    name - integer

foods
    id - integer (primary key)
    name - string
    foodGroup_id - integer (foreign key)
    portion_id - integer (foreign key)
```

and these are my models

```
class Food extends Model
{
    public function food_group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\FoodGroup');
    }

    public function portion(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Portion');
    }
}

class FoodGroup extends Model
{
    public function foods(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Food');
    }
}

class FoodGroup extends Model
{
    public function foods(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Food');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to show some code that is failing to get an answer. This way the question is too broad, and nobody will code this for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('foodGroup/{id}/portions/{id}/foods',function($foodGroup, $portion){
    return Food::where([
      'foodGroup_id',$foodGroup,
      'portion_id',$portion
    ])->get();
}
```

You can also use [Route-Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) if you want to have access to the `foodGroup` and `portion` models instead of just the ids